# False dependency issue for the Fermi architecture

Tags: cuda, nsight

I am trying to achieve "`3`-way overlapping" using `3` streams as in the examples in [CUDA streams and concurrency webinar](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc-express/2011/presentations/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf). But I couldn't achieve it.

I have Geforce GT 550M (Fermi Architecture with one copy engine) and I am using Windows 7 (64 bit).

Here is the code that I have written.

```
#include <iostream>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

// includes, project
#include "helper_cuda.h"
#include "helper_functions.h" // helper utility functions 

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

#define DATA_SIZE 6000000
#define NUM_THREADS 32
#define NUM_BLOCKS 16
#define NUM_STREAMS 3

__global__ void kernel(const int *in, int *out, int dataSize)
{
    int start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int end =  dataSize;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x) 
    {
        out[i] = in[i] * in[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int dataSize = DATA_SIZE;
    int *h_in = new int[dataSize];
    int *h_out = new int[dataSize];
    int *h_groundTruth = new int[dataSize];

    // Input population
    for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
        h_in[i] = 5;

    for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
        h_out[i] = 0;

    // CPU calculation for ground truth
    for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
        h_groundTruth[i] = h_in[i] * h_in[i];

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    checkCudaErrors( cudaSetDevice(0) );

    int *d_in = 0;
    int *d_out = 0;
    int streamSize = dataSize / NUM_STREAMS;
    size_t memSize = dataSize * sizeof(int);
    size_t streamMemSize = memSize / NUM_STREAMS;

    checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_in, memSize) );
    checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_out, memSize) );

    // registers host memory as page-locked (required for asynch cudaMemcpyAsync)
    checkCudaErrors(cudaHostRegister(h_in, memSize, cudaHostRegisterPortable));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaHostRegister(h_out, memSize, cudaHostRegisterPortable));

    // set kernel launch config
    dim3 nThreads = dim3(NUM_THREADS,1,1);
    dim3 nBlocks = dim3(NUM_BLOCKS,1,1);

    cout << "GPU Kernel Configuration : " << endl;
    cout << "Number of Streams :\t" << NUM_STREAMS << " with size: \t" << streamSize << endl;
    cout << "Number of Threads :\t" << nThreads.x << "\t" << nThreads.y << "\t" << nThreads.z << endl;
    cout << "Number of Blocks :\t" << nBlocks.x << "\t" << nBlocks.y << "\t" << nBlocks.z << endl;

    // create cuda stream
    cudaStream_t streams[NUM_STREAMS];
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamCreate(&streams[i]));

    // create cuda event handles
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaEventCreate(&start));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaEventCreate(&stop));

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    // overlapped execution using version 2

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
    {
        int offset = i * streamSize;
        cudaMemcpyAsync(&d_in[offset], &h_in[offset], streamMemSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,     streams[i]);
    }

    //cudaMemcpy(d_in, h_in, memSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
    {
        int offset = i * streamSize;
        dim3 subKernelBlock = dim3((int)ceil((float)nBlocks.x / 2));

        //kernel<<<nBlocks, nThreads, 0, streams[i]>>>(&d_in[offset], &d_out[offset],   streamSize);
        kernel<<<subKernelBlock, nThreads, 0, streams[i]>>>(&d_in[offset], &d_out[offset],   streamSize/2);
        kernel<<<subKernelBlock, nThreads, 0, streams[i]>>>(&d_in[offset + streamSize/2],    &d_out[offset +  streamSize/2], streamSize/2);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
    {
        int offset = i * streamSize;
        cudaMemcpyAsync(&h_out[offset], &d_out[offset], streamMemSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,   streams[i]);
    }



    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamSynchronize(streams[i]));

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamSynchronize(0));

    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    float gpu_time = 0;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaEventElapsedTime(&gpu_time, start, stop));


    // release resources
    checkCudaErrors(cudaEventDestroy(start));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaEventDestroy(stop));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaHostUnregister(h_in));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaHostUnregister(h_out));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_in));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_out));

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamDestroy(streams[i]));

    cudaDeviceReset();  

    cout << "Execution Time of GPU: " << gpu_time << "ms" << endl;


    // GPU output check
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)       
        sum += h_groundTruth[i] - h_out[i];

    cout << "Error between CPU and GPU: " << sum << endl;

    delete[] h_in;
    delete[] h_out;
    delete[] h_groundTruth;

    return 0;
}
```

Using Nsight for profiling, I have this result:

[image]

It may seem correct, but why does the D2H transfer in stream #1 only start when the last kernel launch of stream #2 and not before?
I tried also to use `8` streams (just by changing `NUM_STREAM` to `8`) to achieve such a "`3`-way overlap" and here is the result:

[image]

The interesting thing is that when I use `8` streams, the overlappings between computation and memory transfers seem to be much better.

What is the reason for this problem? Is it due to WDDM driver or is there something wrong with my program?

Comment: I think this is a false dependency issue, see also the [Hyper-Q Example](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/simpleHyperQ/doc/HyperQ.pdf).

Comment: Can you be specific about what you mean by 3-way overlapping?  Are you trying to see a D2H memcpy, a compute kernel(s), and an H2D memcpy simultaneously?  I think that is the usual meaning of 3-way overlap.

Comment: @RobertCrovella If I comment out the second kernel call, my timeline (running on a GeForce 540M) shows that the D2H of the first stream starts exactly after the last H2D of the third stream (no idle time in the memory transfers). I think the OP likes to observe the same behavior also for his case. However, from the above timeline, the D2H of the first stream starts only after the second kernel call of the second stream has finished and not immediately after the H2D of the third stream. This is my understanding of his post.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. What @JackOLantern understand is exactly what I am trying to achieve. With 3-way overlap, I meant that in a given time 3 streams actively transferring data or executing kernel. If you look at the first image, in the time interval 0.08 - 0.082, I was expecting the D2H transfer start in that interval since there is no other transfer active and the copy engine is available.

Comment: @JackoLantern, what OS are you using? Do you think WDDM can effect? Or is there a better way to issue the kernels so that this false dependency is resolved? Thank you for pointing out the false dependency, I was not aware of this issue :)

Comment: Perhaps you should study the difference between slides 21 and 22 in the presentation you linked, and then figure out which of those approaches you are implementing ("depth first" or "breadth first"). Once you have done that, you may find that one is better than the other as indicated in the slides. You won't get the full benefit as indicated on slide 22, since you have only one copy engine. Since you have only one copy engine, "3-way overlapping" could only mean 1 copy plus 2 compute streams, overlapping. But there is nothing special about this vs. 1 copy plus 3 compute streams, for example.

Comment: There are at least 3 methods for discovering whether WDDM batching is having an impact, at least one of which you know already.  1. Insert `cudaEventQuery()` calls, 2. Use the latest version of nsight VSE, which can display information about the WDDM command queue and 3. switch to linux (or a TCC GPU on windows).  I suggest you attempt some of that yourself, rather than asking others to do that work for you.  Confirming WDDM batching is not something that can be reasonably ascertained purely by inspection of code.

Comment: @RobertCrovella I'm somewhat confused and I hope you can clarify me the things. The OP's problem is that the first D2H copy (first stream) waits some time after the last H2D copy (third stream) is accomplished. This does not happen if I comment the second kernel, see [here](http://derp.co.uk/6cb2b). Moving to the depth-first approach seems to produce worse results, see [here](http://derp.co.uk/11f90), than the breadth-first approach, see [here](http://derp.co.uk/ce429). The code for the depth-first approach is reported [here](http://pastebin.com/hZZdYwYf).

Comment: @RobertCrovella If I run the breadth-first approach on a Kepler K20c, I obtain the result reported [here](http://derp.co.uk/ac2e0). I note in this case that the dual copy engine is not being exploited.

Comment: @RobertCrovella In other words, why is there the time gap in the red circle [here](http://derp.co.uk/39e7b) for the breadth-first approach? I would say that even without a dual-copy engine the first D2H copy could start before the time it is actually starting. Is this a false dependency issue? Am I wrong?

Comment: The slide deck was crafted in the Fermi time frame, and the breadth-first vs. depth-first recommendation in that deck was fermi specific.  K20c is not fermi.  However the OP's GPU is fermi.  Also, I'm really not very interested (in case you haven't deduced it yet) in chasing around WDDM results.  WDDM batching is an unpredicatable interloper that gets in the way, and it's not a serious environment for hi-performance work.  I see little utility in fleshing out what is actually going on in a specific WDDM case.  I'll chew on it some more.  Yes, it may be false dependency.

Comment: I would agree with @JackOLantern that it appears to be a false dependency issue in Fermi.  I created 4 program variants (breadth-first single kernel, breadth-first double kernel, depth-first single kernel, and depth-first double kernel) and ran them on 3 different architectures (Quadro1000 = Fermi/1 Copy engine, Quadro5000 = Fermi/2 Copy engines, K20m = Kepler/2 Copy engines), all under linux.  The Q1000 results essentially duplicated the OP's, so I conclude the gap is not WDDM batching.  K20m produced identical and ideal results regardless of the 4 cases tested.

Comment: I saw slightly differing behavior between Q1000 and Q5000, which I attribute to single vs. dual copy engines.  I believe the slide deck's recommendation between depth-first and breadth-first is still valid for Fermi with 2 copy engines *and* only a single kernel in each stream.

Comment: Niether windows WDDM, nor Fermi, nor GPUs with one copy engine, it seems, are conducive to achieving ideal results under a variety of conditions.  Ideal results under a variety of conditions are most likely to be achieved on a cc3.5 or higher GPU with 2 copy engines, under linux.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Thank you very much for all your tests and explanations. All my tests above have been performed on a GeForce GT540M (Fermi), except the last one done on a Kepler K20c. Would you like to post an answer? This post can serve as a good example of false dependency for future users.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the comments above, it seems that the OP's problem is a **false dependency** issue, suffered by the Fermi architecture and solved by the Hyper-Q feature of the Kepler architecture.

To summarize, the OP is highlighting the fact that the first D2H transfer (stream #1) does not start immediately after the last H2D (stream #3) finishes, while in principle *it could*. The time gap is highlighted by the red circle in the following figure (henceforth, but for the differently specified, all the tests refer to a GeForce GT540M belonging to the Fermi family):

[image]

The OP's approach is a **breadth-first** approach, which operates according to the following scheme:

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
    cudaMemcpyAsync(..., cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,   streams[i]);

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
{
    kernel_launch_1<<<..., 0, streams[i]>>>(...);
    kernel_launch_2<<<..., 0, streams[i]>>>(...);
}

for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
    cudaMemcpyAsync(..., cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,   streams[i]);
```

Using a **depth-first** approach, operating according to the following scheme

```
for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
{
    cudaMemcpyAsync(...., cudaMemcpyHostToDevice, streams[i]);

    kernel_launch_1<<<...., 0, streams[i]>>>(....);
    kernel_launch_2<<<...., 0, streams[i]>>>(....);

    cudaMemcpyAsync(...., cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,   streams[i]);
}
```

does not seem to improve the situation, according to the following timeline (the depth-first code is reported at the bottom of the answer), but it seems to show a worse overlapping:

[image]

Under the breadth-first approach, and commenting the second kernel launch, the first D2H copy starts immediately as it can, as reported by the following timeline:

[image]

Finally, running the code on a Kepler K20c, the problem does not show up, as illustrated by the following figure:

[image]

Here is the code for the depth-first approach:

```
#include <iostream>

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

// includes, project
#include "helper_cuda.h"
#include "helper_functions.h" // helper utility functions

#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

#define DATA_SIZE 6000000
#define NUM_THREADS 32
#define NUM_BLOCKS 16
#define NUM_STREAMS 3

__global__ void kernel(const int *in, int *out, int dataSize)
{
    int start = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int end =  dataSize;
    for (int i = start; i < end; i += blockDim.x * gridDim.x)
    {
        out[i] = in[i] * in[i];
    }
}

int main()
{
    const int dataSize = DATA_SIZE;
    int *h_in = new int[dataSize];
    int *h_out = new int[dataSize];
    int *h_groundTruth = new int[dataSize];

    // Input population
    for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
        h_in[i] = 5;

    for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
        h_out[i] = 0;

    // CPU calculation for ground truth
    for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)
        h_groundTruth[i] = h_in[i] * h_in[i];

    // Choose which GPU to run on, change this on a multi-GPU system.
    checkCudaErrors( cudaSetDevice(0) );

    int *d_in = 0;
    int *d_out = 0;
    int streamSize = dataSize / NUM_STREAMS;
    size_t memSize = dataSize * sizeof(int);
    size_t streamMemSize = memSize / NUM_STREAMS;

    checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_in, memSize) );
    checkCudaErrors( cudaMalloc( (void **)&d_out, memSize) );

    // registers host memory as page-locked (required for asynch cudaMemcpyAsync)
    checkCudaErrors(cudaHostRegister(h_in, memSize, cudaHostRegisterPortable));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaHostRegister(h_out, memSize, cudaHostRegisterPortable));

    // set kernel launch config
    dim3 nThreads = dim3(NUM_THREADS,1,1);
    dim3 nBlocks = dim3(NUM_BLOCKS,1,1);

    cout << "GPU Kernel Configuration : " << endl;
    cout << "Number of Streams :\t" << NUM_STREAMS << " with size: \t" << streamSize << endl;
    cout << "Number of Threads :\t" << nThreads.x << "\t" << nThreads.y << "\t" << nThreads.z << endl;
    cout << "Number of Blocks :\t" << nBlocks.x << "\t" << nBlocks.y << "\t" << nBlocks.z << endl;

    // create cuda stream
    cudaStream_t streams[NUM_STREAMS];
    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamCreate(&streams[i]));

    // create cuda event handles
    cudaEvent_t start, stop;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaEventCreate(&start));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaEventCreate(&stop));

    cudaEventRecord(start, 0);

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
    {
        int offset = i * streamSize;

        cudaMemcpyAsync(&d_in[offset], &h_in[offset], streamMemSize, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice,     streams[i]);

        dim3 subKernelBlock = dim3((int)ceil((float)nBlocks.x / 2));

        kernel<<<subKernelBlock, nThreads, 0, streams[i]>>>(&d_in[offset], &d_out[offset],   streamSize/2);
        kernel<<<subKernelBlock, nThreads, 0, streams[i]>>>(&d_in[offset + streamSize/2],    &d_out[offset +  streamSize/2], streamSize/2);

        cudaMemcpyAsync(&h_out[offset], &d_out[offset], streamMemSize, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost,   streams[i]);
    }



    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamSynchronize(streams[i]));

    cudaEventRecord(stop, 0);

    checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamSynchronize(0));

    checkCudaErrors(cudaDeviceSynchronize());

    float gpu_time = 0;
    checkCudaErrors(cudaEventElapsedTime(&gpu_time, start, stop));


    // release resources
    checkCudaErrors(cudaEventDestroy(start));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaEventDestroy(stop));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaHostUnregister(h_in));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaHostUnregister(h_out));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_in));
    checkCudaErrors(cudaFree(d_out));

    for(int i = 0; i < NUM_STREAMS; i++)
        checkCudaErrors(cudaStreamDestroy(streams[i]));

    cudaDeviceReset();  

    cout << "Execution Time of GPU: " << gpu_time << "ms" << endl;


    // GPU output check
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < dataSize; i++)      
        sum += h_groundTruth[i] - h_out[i];

    cout << "Error between CPU and GPU: " << sum << endl;

    delete[] h_in;
    delete[] h_out;
    delete[] h_groundTruth;

    return 0;
}
```